# How can I convert a string to a list in Python using a for loop?

Tags: string, list, function, for-loop

Here's what I have:

def reverse(text):
    opposite = []
    for character in text:
       stuff = opposite.append(character)
    return stuff

Is there something wrong with this for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you use the split method instead it will return a list

```
text.split()
```

Or even

```
list(text)
```

Which would list out each character

Answer (score 0):

```
yourstring='welcome'
l=[]
for char in yourstring:
      l.append(char)
print l
```